# use emailjs-imap-client in nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm using emailjs-imap-client (@cull/imap) to read emails in my nativescript/angular project. I write a simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import Client from '@cull/imap';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ImapService {
    private _client: Client;
    constructor() {
        this._client = new Client({
            host: 'my.email.server',
            port: 993,
            user: 'username',
            pass: 'password'
          });
    }
}
```

But the compiler says that 'net' and 'tls' cannot be resolved. After installing 'net' and 'tls' using "npm install", I get following errors:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function
System.err: TypeError: (0 , _ramda.memoize) is not a function
System.err: File: (file: node_modules\emailjs-imap-handler\dist\formal-syntax.js:20:0)
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: ../node_modules/emailjs-imap-handler/dist/formal-syntax.js(file: node_modules\emailjs-imap-handler\dist\formal-syntax.js:20:0)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:753:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
System.err:     at ../node_modules/emailjs-imap-handler/dist/compiler.js(file: node_modules\emailjs-imap-handler\dist\compiler.js:116:20)
System.err:     at __webpack_require__(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:753:0)
System.err:     at fn(file: src\webpack\bootstrap:120:0)
```

So what's wrong with imap-client. How can I use it in nativescript-angular?
Thank you in advance!

Xinyu

Comment: What is the version of your `emailjs-imap-handler` and `ramdajs` in package lock?

Comment: emailjs-imap-hanlder: 3.0.2,
ramda: 0.26.1

Comment: The issue is related to the package itself. `memoize` is not a valid method in recent version of `ramdajs`. The TS files in the repo are updated, but ones in the dist folder seems not, may be the dist folder wasn't updated by the author.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. If I replace memoize with memoizeWith, I get other errors (something relatived with browser) for mobile app. But it compiles without error for the web site works ( I use nativescript shared). It seems that the package is not written for mobile apps. Do you have some advices on how to correct this ramda-error or is there any other package to read mails?

Comment: Did you mean the same one works when you compile for web? Can you share a sample project?

Comment: I find out that imap cannot be used on the client side. Because the web browser cannot open tcp sockets. Maybe this is the reason why I had to install 'net' additionally, which was not correct. I have to build a backend service, using e.g. REST APIs, so that the app can use them to read mails. If I am wrong, please let me know. Thank you!